# Can I run vue-cli-service serve at non-root for testing purposes?

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

When I launch `vue-cli-service serve` for testing on my dev machine, it hosts my project at the root URL (i.e. "/") by default. I would like to launch `vue-cli-service serve` at a non-root path (i.e. "/test/") so I can test relative paths, redirects, environment variables, etc, before deploying out to our production server. Is there a way to launch `vue-cli-service serve` at a non-root path for testing purposes? Also, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath

Comment: Thank you @EstusFlask, that fixed it! If you want to post that as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score -1):

Copy your build output dir(default  dist) and paste in the  dist ,so there will be two folder named dist(one is the child of the other), then rename the child
dist to test, hope it's helpful